# Why upscale CPUs consumes more power even when idle?

Tags: cpu, power, power-management

A core i7 have a tdp around 80W and whereas a N3150 is 6W.

My question is what prevents founders to build CPUs with a proportionate consumption with performance. Said differntly, why can I not have a powerful CPU which have a low power consumption when I do not want to have heavy performances?

Comment: Are you asking why fast high performance processors require more power? They are fast because of the silicon.

Comment: But does it? Please provide some reference.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is this: To do a certain amount of work requires a certain number of transistors to change state. Doing work at a higher rate means more transistors changing state per second. It takes a certain amount of energy to change a transistor's state and effectively, all of this energy winds up being dissipated as heat. So doing work faster means dissipating more heat.

There are three big exceptions to this:

1. Newer manufacturing techniques can allow a transistor to switch state using less energy.
2. Manufacturing techniques can be optimized for high performance (typical for desktop CPUs) or optimized for low power consumption (typical for mobile CPUs).
3. Clever design can reduce the number of transistors that need to change state for a given amount of work.

This explains why newer CPUs can do much more work than older CPUs that dissipate the same amount of power.

Comment: Case in point: There are desktop Intel CPUs that are [35 W](http://ark.intel.com/products/88200/Intel-Core-i7-6700T-Processor-8M-Cache-up-to-3_60-GHz) and mobile Intel CPUs that are [4.5 W](http://ark.intel.com/products/88199/Intel-Core-m7-6Y75-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_10-GHz)

Comment: Don't forget about core parking as saving energy also.

Answer (score 2):

You can, power options in the OS can reduce minimum clock, I've seen 4th gen i5's clocked to 800Mhz by windows power plans and consuming tiny amounts of power.

The downside to this is current gen CPUs take a nonzero amount of time to respond to increased workloads so when the processing power is needed users can experience a "lag" before they clock back up.

Also note TDP is MAX consumption, not what it will actually use with Speedstep dynamically clocking the cores.

Comment: This does nothing to answer the question of why a "fast" CPU draws more power at idle than a "slow" CPU.

Answer (score 1):

The key point that other answers are missing is that yes, a fast CPU has more silicon/transistors than a slow one, BUT - that implies more overhead even when they're not in use. Dialing down the clock speed can help, but there is a minimum to just keep things running at all.

Analogously, a large car engine may have more power than a smaller one, and in turn consumes more fuel even at idle purely because it takes more energy to keep it turning even at a minimum sustainable speed.

As @moab mentioned in a comment, some CPUs implement a feature known as 'Core Parking' (or broadly PStates), which allows a core to be disabled entirely (clockspeed 0, power removed) when not needed. This avoids consuming the minimum power needed to keep a core running by (almost) effectively making the CPU have fewer cores.
In our analogy this can be compared to engines which have say 8 cylinders but can disable 2 or 4 of them, thus avoiding the fuel consumption and the losses of compression (but still incurring overheads due to friction of the extra parts).